# How to open the parent folder of my OSX Application using Swift

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift

I am trying to make my OSX App to open its parents folder in the Finder.

My Swift/Cocoa app is located here:  /myApp/myApp.app

I need to open /myApp/ folder in the Finder when someone click on a MenuItem.

Here is my current code:

```
@IBAction func clickShowFolder(sender: NSMenuItem) {
    let pathToApplication: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath
    let showFolder = NSTask()
    showFolder.launchPath = "/usr/bin/open"
    showFolder.arguments = [pathToApplication]
    showFolder.launch()
}
```

This code will open the /myApp/myApp.app instead of /myApp/

Do you have any better idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath.stringByDeletingLastPathComponent
```